# Java MergeSort Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MergeSortLines {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  //String []list ;
  try{
     Scanner tn = new Scanner(new File("phj.txt"));
     while(tn.hasNext()){
        String temp = tn.next();
        String otherTemp = removeSpecial(temp);
        for(int r =0; r<list.size();r++){

        list.add(otherTemp);
     }
     }
  }
  catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println("Sorry there was an error");

  }


  mergeSort(list);



   }

   public static void mergeSort(String[]a){
      if(a.length >= 2){
         String[] left = new String[a.length/2];
         String[]right = new String[a.length-a.length/2];
         System.out.println("Left:  " + Arrays.toString(left));
         System.out.println("Right:  " + Arrays.toString(right));


         for(int i = 0 ; i< left.length;i++){
            left[i] = a[i];
         }

         for (int b = 0; b <right.length;b++){
            right[b] = a[b+a.length/2];
         }

         mergeSort(left);
         mergeSort(right);
         merge(a, left,right);
      }
   }
   public static void merge(String[]result,String[]left,String[]right){
      int i1 = 0;
      int i2 = 0;
      for(int i =0;i<result.length;i++){
         if(i2 >=right.length|| i1< left.length && 
left[i1].compareToIgnoreCase(right[i2]) < 0){
            result[i] = left[i1];
            i1++;
         }
         else{

            result[i] = right[i2];
            i2++;
         }

      }

   }
```

I've tried to use an ArrayList but I get the following error:

MergeSortLines.java:25: error: incompatible types: ArrayList cannot be converted to String[]

I understand ArrayLists are faster than regular Arrays. I have tried to convert the Array to ArrayList, but I keep getting errors. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: *ArrayLists are faster than regular Arrays* - are they?

Comment: Have you just *read* the error message. What is unclear about it? What don't you understand? If you ask for a knife, and I give you a fork, will you be happy? If a method asks for a String array, and you give it an ArrayList, will it be happy?

Comment: I just need help understanding the error, also yes I thought ArrayList was faster but I used them here because they are dynamic.

Comment: `"I just need help understanding the error"`, what part of `"incompatible types: ArrayList cannot be converted to String[]"` remains unclear?

Comment: it is literally impossible to get an error message more clear: `mergeSort(list);`, `list` is an ArrayList but the methods only accepts `String[]`

Comment: @JBNizet but I don't understand why. The ArrayList is set to take Strings anyway

Comment: @Daniel A `String` is a type that's different from `ArrayList`. The `ArrayList` is being used as a *container* of `String`s, but is not the same as a `String`; a `Car` can contain `Passenger`s, but is not the same as a `Passenger`

Comment: What your method expects is a String[]. An array of Strings. An ArrayList<String> is not an array of Strings. It's a different type. To continue on the car metaphor, a Car contains passengers. A bus contains passengers too. And so does a plane. But a Car and a Plane are two very different things. And you can't just use a plane on roads, because roads expect cars, not planes.

Comment: Can I just change what the methods expect to an ArrayList?

Comment: You can do that. But you should take a step back, and read an introductory tutorial/book about Java, objects and types first.

Comment: I will/am , but is there any simple way I can fix this program ?

Comment: The simplest way would be to use the standard sorting algorithm coming with Java. But you're writing this to learn, right? And it made it clear that you don't understand types. So, before going further and write code you wouldn't understand, read about types, and understand them.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
mergeSort(list.toArray(new String[list.size()]))
```

instead of

```
mergeSort(list);
```

> I understand ArrayLists are faster than regular Arrays.

False. ArrayLists using regular Arrays inside, so ArrayList is little bit slow than regular Arrays (in most case, it is doesn't matter)